# Определение 1 кнопки для отправки формы

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу сюда ибо не смог найти ничего нормального в гугле: как определить для формы всего 1 кнопку, которая будет запускать действие над нею, или ограничить остальные кнопки, находящиеся в ней, от запуска этого же действия?

Answer (score 2):

В тега `button` есть атрибут `type`, который определяет ее поведение в форме.

- `button` - обычная кнопка
- `submit` - отправка формы
- `reset` - очистка формы

По умолчанию `type` имеет значение `submit`. То есть если не задать этот атрибут, кнопка по умолчанию будет отправлять форму.

То есть для решеня вашей проблемы каждая кнопка формы должна иметь атрибут `type="button"` и только одна - `type="submit"`.

---

Источник: http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/type